# Heroku - Maven app with local dependencies works perfect in local but is not deploying

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have an Heroku app with some local dependencies, which I have installed by the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile="lib\com\sforce\soap\partner\1.0\partner-1.0.jar" -DgroupId="com.sforce.soap.partner" -DartifactId=partner -Dversion="1.0" -Dpackaging=jar
```

With this I do a mvn package and a clean install, and my app works perfect in my local environment. The problem that I have is when I try to deploy this app to Heroku, because it fails with "Could not resolve dependencies error" (especially fails in partner.jar dependency). I have tried to install my jars in the heroku console with the previous command but it says that mvn command is not found.

What can I do to solve this? This is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.aisfg</groupId>
<artifactId>ais-salesforce-heroku-bloomber</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin> 
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>Service</mainClass>
                        <name>service</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
        <version>35.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mozilla/rhino -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mozilla</groupId>
        <artifactId>rhino</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://www.stringtemplate.org/ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>ST4</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20200518</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LOCAL DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.bloomberglp.blpapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>blpapi</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sforce.soap.partner</groupId>
        <artifactId>partner</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sforce.soap.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>enterprise</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version> 
    </dependency>


</dependencies> 
<!-- <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>project_lib</id>
        <name>Repository in project's lib dir</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/lib</url> 
    </repository>
</repositories> -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mvn install:install-file` installs the dependency (by default) in your local repository (defaults to `~/.m2/repository` under Linux/macOS). This will make the dependency available to Maven on your local machine, but not during the build process in Heroku as you observed.

Using this command in the Herkou console would also (if `mvn` would be available) not work for a couple of reasons:

- [The file system of Heroku Dynos is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem)
- The console runs for your compiled application, not for the build system

However, you can make this work. This will require checking in your JAR file to Git so Heroku has access to it during the build. This has a drawback: if you update the file often, your repo size will grow quickly since Git can no longer only store deltas between versions. However, I think this seems to be a reasonable use-case here.

1. Add a new repository to your `pom.xml` that points to a directory in your project directory:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-maven-repository</id>
        <url>file:///${project.basedir}/maven-repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

2. Create that directory (make sure you're running all commands while you're in your project directory):

`mkdir maven-repository`

3. Deploy your artifact to that repository:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.sforce.soap.partner -DartifactId=partner -Dversion=1.0 -Durl=file:./maven-repository/ -DrepositoryId=local-maven-repository -DupdateReleaseInfo=true -Dfile=lib\com\sforce\soap\partner\1.0\partner-1.0.jar
```

4. Add your changes and dependency JARs to Git and deploy to Heroku:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add local dependency"
git push heroku master
```

If you don't want to check-in your binary, you'll have to have a remotely accessible Nexus repo with your dependency. You can protect it with a password and set it up on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-a-custom-maven-settings-xml#using-password-protected-repositories

Comment: Thanks! I installed the dependencies by the mvn deploy command but using another args and it was failing. Finally your code allowed my app to deploy and execute.